# Why I see unused Bolts in Storm UI

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am experimenting with configs to find suitable ones for my system and I have a problem that for some reason some of my bolts don't work ([unused bolts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQKwr.png)). I have 15 spouts, 18 partitions (before it I had 18 spouts and 18 bolts for 18 partitions but had the same issue with 2 bolts), 15 bolts. Once I tried to set 36 spouts and something about 54 bolts but almost half of the bolts were not used.

Did somebody have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the final end I did not get why it's happening but it was fixed after I recalculated resources (cpu\mem), based on total memory\cpu of machines configured manually such props:

```
nimbus.childopts -Xmx
ui.childopts -Xmx
supervisor.childopts: -Xmx
supervisor.cpu.capacity
supervisor.memory.capacity.mb
topology.component.cpu.pcore.percent
```

After this, my problem disappeared. Even if I set big number of bolts, etc. So resource props are very important for storm.